# Terraform Lookup returning a block

Tags: terraform

I am attempting to only assign a log_config to a subnet, if the subnet name is in the "file_one.tf sample" below. To accomplish the conditional logic I am using the lookup function to only return a "log_config" block if the name matches a name in the variable referenced in "file_one.tf".

The error I am getting is:
An argument named "log_config" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block type of "log_config"

Would someone please help out with this? Or present a more elegant approach to assigning blocks to resources with conditional logic?

Thank you

```
# file_one.tf sample
locals {
  subnets = {
     "one" = {
        "name" = "one"
        local_config = {
          aggregation_interval = "INTERVAL_10_SEC"
          metadata             = "INCLUDE_ALL_METADATA"
        }
  }
}

# file_two.tf
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges" {
  foreach       = local.subnets
  name          = each_value.name
  ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/16"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.custom-test.id
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "tf-test-secondary-range-update1"
    ip_cidr_range = "192.168.10.0/24"
  }
  log_config      = lookup(each.value, log_config, null)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to pass a `map` type as a value for an argument, and the resource schema is expecting a block type and not an argument with a `map`. You would need a dynamic block for this situation:

```
dynamic "log_config" {
  for_each = lookup(each.value, log_config, [])

  content {
    aggregation_interval = log_config.value["aggregation_interval"]
    metadata             = log_config.value["metadata"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key that you want in said map is called `local_config`, no? When `lookup()` returns its default value is `null`, which is also not a block. But here I believe you want to pass in a string key to the lookup function:

```
# file_two.tf
{
  # ...
  name       = each.value.name
  # ...
  log_config = lookup(each.value, "local_config", null)
}
```